# Generate variable if greater than mean, by group

Tags: stata

I would like to generate a variable `newvar` which is equal to 1 for observations which are above the average for two variables (`var1` and `var2`), where this average is not the global dataset average, but the average of the observations within the group to which observation belongs (variable `group`).

Here is a replicable example:

```
clear
input str59 group float(var1 var2)
"Algeria"  0 .000033156746
"Algeria"  0  .00017467902
"Algeria"  0  .00024518964
"Algeria"  0    .000624308
"Angola"  0   .0007729884
"Angola"  0   .0014512347
"Angola"  0    .001463664
"Angola"  0   .0015886982
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do this. Start with an all-zero counter variable, above_grp_means. Loop through the two variables, calculating the group-specific mean, and adding 1 to above_grp_means if the value is above the mean. Then recode above_grp_means to a binary flag.

```
gen above_grp_means = 0

foreach x of varlist var1 var2 {
    bysort group: egen mean = mean(`x')
    replace above_grp_means = above_grp_means + 1 if `x'>=mean & !missing(`x')
    drop mean
}

replace above_grp_means = cond(above_grp_means==2,1,0)
```

Stata conceptualizes missing data as a very large positive number, but the second part of the if condition handles that in case you have missing data.

Comment: Plus one from me. By the way, this question is a slight variation of the one i answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204041/). Perhaps you will be more lucky and the OP will not delete it.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Deletion of that sort is obnoxious, but hopefully the OP has understood your warning. I generally will flag such disappearing questions for reopening.